# sifr fade problems on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, sifr, fade

i use a sIFR title in a list on my website. i fade list-items out and in. works fine. but in IE when i fades, the sIFR title suddenly has a black background. but just during the fade-animation. saw that also on other websites...

any ideas or former posts? thanks!

Comment: Does the title have a background-color? Can you give it one?

Answer (score 0):

Opacity and Flash movies + IE never goes very well. Are you using transparent PNGs or related hacks? Those might also be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

i just use a sifr font. means transparent flash. no png. but i guess thats a IE problem...